# Why we use add_filter in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I've read tutorial from codex.wordpress.org but I could not understand why it is used in wordpress. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`add_filter` is used to modify content/data prior to display.

You can filter any of the hooks at http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference. For example, adding a filter to `the_content` would allow you to tweak the content - perhaps something like adding Amazon.com affiliate codes to links to Amazon products.